# how to execute command prompt from php

Tags: javascript, php, cmd, imagemagick, montage

As am very new to php.
I have the following command as:

```
cd E:\PHP\home_php\img\tmp
E:
montage -mode concatenate -tile 3x3 *.png result.png
```

I want to execute the command from cmd.exe in php(if possible from javascript too).
Right now I have to execute .bat file but that file has some static value. I need to pass few dynamic value. How can I open cmd with required command.
I tried php montage but I need .bat kind of thing in cmd from php/JS.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :`echo exec('your command');`

Comment: u mean:

    function execInBackground() { 
    $cmd1='cd E:/PHP/home_php/satimg/tmp';
    $cmd2='E:';
    $cmd3='montage -mode concatenate -tile 3x3 *.png result.png';
        if (substr(php_uname(), 0, 7) == "Windows"){ 
            pclose(popen("start /B ". $cmd1, "r"));  
            pclose(popen("start /B ". $cmd2, "r"));  
            pclose(popen("start /B ". $cmd3, "r"));  
        } 
        else { 
            exec($cmd . " > /dev/null &");   
        } 
    }

Answer (score 0):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php you can also use backticks for some weird reason: http://php.net/exec

Answer (score 0):

You can use number of PHP funcions to execute system code:

`shell_exec("your command")` would execute code and return an output to you
`system("your command",  $returnCode)` would execute your command and return numerical status of your command
`exec("your command", $outputArray, $returnCode)` would execute command and return your output line by line in outputArray + return code

Before asking such a simple question you really should first go to http://php.net and search for required functionality instead of asking it here.

Comment: I have seen that but how to add command as a batch command. I checked few codes of it but not worked thats why I posted here. can you give example of batch command in windows cmd.exe

Comment: You can join separate commands with " && " symbold. For example: `cd .. && dir` would move you up in directory tree and execure DIR command.